# How to manipulate DocumentFragment in react?

Tags: reactjs, range, documentfragment

I am working on an ePub app, currently I want to display a note/highlight section on a sidebar.

I am able to get the [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) object (by the document.crateRange method), then call  cloneContents from it which it return a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) object.

I had tried to create a ref object, and able to append the DocumentFragment object into it. However, I want to wrap the DocumentFragment object inside a checkbox element.

I had tried with something like

```js
<Checkbox>
{documentFragment object}
</Checkbox>
```

which will throw error `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object DocumentFragment]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`.

I know I could just get the textContent only from this DocumentFragment object, however I want to keep the styles came with it, and also wrap it inside a checkbox. How could I achieve this in react?

P.S.
`documentFragment object` looks like this on log:
[image]

Comment: Can you add to your question what the DocumentFragment object looks like?

Comment: [A DocumentFragment object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment), it looks like jsx.element but react is not aware of